# How to know the extension of uploaded file before saving the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
     HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[j];
     string fileName = file.FileName;
     string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filepath + file.FileName);
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)
     {
        string pathToSave_100 = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filepath) + fileName + fileExtension;
        if (File.Exists(pathToSave_100))
        {
           File.Delete(pathToSave_100);
           file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
        }
        else
        {
           file.SaveAs(pathToSave_100);
        }
     }
```

Comment: So what is the problem with this code? Extension can be found from the magic numbers of the byte array which represent the file.

Comment: @mybirthname Here, file get saved without any Extension. Thanks

Comment: That's what he meant, if there's no file extension you must inspect the 'magic bytes' at the beginning of the file. There is lots of information about this if you search online.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
string strFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
```

Comment: Getting null/empty extension in "strFileExtension". Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Are you sure your file variable is not returning null?

Comment: OP says in a comment that these files have no extension, this is why this code throws an error. He needs to inspect the 'magic bytes' of the file. There are answers on how to do this already.